# 14.10 only boots to UEFI Interactive shell

Tags: boot, virtualbox, uefi, 14.10

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 on a VirtualBox VM. It installed fine, I was even able to install Guest Additions and a few apps before shutting it down for the day. Now when I try to boot the VM all that loads is the UEFI Interactive shell.

[image]

How do I get it to boot back into the normal desktop?

Comment: Go into your VirtualBox settings by choosing your Ubuntu VM then Settings. Choose System and then uncheck Enable EFI.

Comment: I just tried that and all it gives me is "no bootable medium found"

Comment: Ah. No wonder. It's because you installed it in EFI mode. You need to make a new virtual machine and install Ubuntu all over again and make sure that box is NOT checked!

Comment: Well that figures.. I didn't do much with it yet anyway so whatever x_x And this is why I VM things 1st lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox boots only in UEFI Interactive shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566315/virtualbox-boots-only-in-uefi-interactive-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Edit `startup.nsh`. Add the line:

```
fs0:\path\to\grubx64.efi
```