# Boot into GRUB from Windows boot manager in UEFI dual boot configuration

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

## TL;DR

It's not possible to add Grub boot entry in Windows Boot Manager.
But something similar can be achieved using a third party boot manager like Rod Smith's rEFInd. 
Installation steps are well explained in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/dfff8321b94fd666eb64eda0382f6813)
But Acer laptops (tested on 3 Acers) *apparently* forgets boot entries and only windows boot manager loads despite refind/grub is present in ESP.
**Acer laptop's UEFI menu has two hidden settings that become available only when you set a password for the UEFI menu. You can then mark any third party boot manager as TRUSTED without signing the boot manager with RSA key (as shown in the gist and many other places). You can disable secure boot too if a password is set. If UEFI is enabled, only TRUSTED boot managers are loaded by UEFI and all others are ignored because of which only windows boots and we incorrectly think UEFI forgets boot entries.**
An alternative is to disable UEFI but why lower the security ourselves when there is a solution?

## The long story

My old laptop used MBR scheme and I was able to install grub on Ubuntu's partition (not on MBR) and then added a boot entry for grub in Windows boot manager.
This enabled me to keep windows boot manager as well as grub.

My new laptop came with Windows 10 pre-installed with UEFI.
I installed Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 with the following partitioning-

```
/boot ext4 1GB
/ (root) ext4 25GB
/home ext4 400GB
```

I thought this will install grub on /boot (It might have, I don't know)

Installation was successful

I rebooted into Windows and ran EasyBCD 2.3 (latest) to add a boot entry for grub in windows boot manager.
But that option was greyed out. EasyBCD say that because I have secure boot enabled some features are not supported. I can see option for adding a boot entry for another Windows OS but the same options are greyed out for linux OSes.

I want to keep both Windows boot manager and GRUB but on separate partitions so that I can goto GRUB from Windows boot manager as I did in my old laptop.

Why?

1. I plan to upgrade to 18.04 LTS and/or  update OS shipped kernel to mainline kernel
2. The GRUB screen is quite scary for my siblings who also use my laptop

**Update 1**: UEFI boot menu (from F12 key) shows only one entry which is for Windows. If grub is present in /boot or /EFI/Ubuntu it should show up in boot menu. 
I have tried reinstalling without a /boot partition but still no luck.

Edit: It's Acer V3-574G-54VY running on i5-5200U. System Information shows-

```
BIOS Version : Insyde Corp V1.35, 30-11-2015
BIOS Mode : UEFI
```

It came with UEFI firmware ("BIOS Version" in System Information) V1.1. I updated it to V1.35 two months ago.

**Update 2:** I followed @RodSmith 's blog and fixed grub not being shown in UEFI boot menu using **efibootmgr**. I am now using GRUB (via shim with SecureBoot Enabled) as the default bootloader. But my question is still unanswered. **How do I add Grub/Ubuntu bootloader entry to Windows Boot Manager?** Does Windows Boot Manager support such configuration? I am in doubt now because when Windows Boot Manager was default, it deleted GRUB boot entry in EFI at every boot.

Another thing worth noting, I did not disable fast startup in Windows probably because of it Ubuntu installer could not install GRUB (or it installed grub but Windows Boot Manager that loaded first because of fast startup, removed it at boot)

**Update 3:** I rebooted to Windows and it deleted GRUB boot entry and made itself default again. Now I m back to where I was.

**Update 4:** I configured boot order from Windows **bcdedit** and now the boot order persists across boots. I had to disable secure boot. Secure Boot toggle is ungreyed after setting Supervisor password in UEFI. I have to enter that password everytime I goto UEFI menu. This probably implies it would be impossible for any app to modify UEFI settings when Secure Boot is disabled. I don't think my UEFI is buggy, it's quite advanced and more secure than other vendors

Comment: With UEFI , you do not need EasyBCD. UEFI itself is also a Boot Manager or menu. So probably press f10 or f12 (check manual on correct key) to get UEFI boot menu. If Secure boot is on, that is the only way you can dual boot. Even grub will not work with secure boot on. Best with most Desktop installs not to use /boot partition. You have to maintain it and make sure  you do not fill it. Newer version should only be keeping 2 kernels but some are still having issues. I think with UEFI grub only actually installs into ESP - efi system partition.

Comment: But Ubuntu installs shim in /boot/shimx64.efi which boots grub from /boot/grubx64.efi in SecureBoot enabled systems. Source [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/228069/605131)

Comment: Actually /EFI/ubuntu is default locations for shimx64.efi & grubx64.efi. And often both are added to UEFI boot entries if Secure boot not on. But one of the work arounds to get crippled UEFI to work is copy & rename shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi as fallback or hard drive boot entry. Live installers use /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi to boot flash drives or external drives.

Comment: UEFI Boot menu shows only one entry and that's for Windows. So I can't access grub from UEFI boot menu also. Do I need to create a FAT32 EFI partition separate for Ubuntu for my configuration to work?

Comment: Only one ESP - efi system partition per device/drive. Ubuntu & Windows easily share the one ESP.  Did you install in BIOS boot mode not UEFI boot mode? How you boot install media is then how it installs.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi What brand/model system? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I have installed in UEFI mode only.

Answer (score 2):

You should first be aware that modern EFI-based computers boot in entirely different ways from older BIOS-based computers. I suspect you're laboring under incorrect BIOS-mode mental models, which is leading you astray. I recommend reading:

- **[Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)** -- This page describes the theory behind EFI-mode booting.
- **[A question and answers on the differences between BIOS and EFI booting on Superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi)** -- This provides the basics of the preceding, but is more concise.
- **[My page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)** -- This page is a more practical introduction to EFI-mode booting than Adam Williamson's blog.
- **[The Ubuntu community wiki entry on UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)** -- This page is a bit disjointed, but is the most Ubuntu-specific introduction to EFI and its issues.

That's admittedly a long reading list. If you have time for just one, I'd go with the first, or possibly the second. The third and fourth are more practical tutorial on installation, but you've already got a working system, albeit one that's not working in quite the way you want.

Of particular importance for this discussion, under EFI, boot loaders are stored as ordinary files in the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) The boot loader to be launched by default is stored in NVRAM, which can be displayed by `sudo efibootmgr -v` in Ubuntu, and modified with other options to `efibootmgr`. (Type `man efibootmgr` for details, in the usual terse manpage style.) Your `/boot` partition holds Linux kernels, GRUB configuration and support files, and a few other boot-related tools; but the main GRUB binary, `grubx64.efi`, is stored on the ESP, which is mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu.

That out of the way, Windows *requires* the Windows boot loader, and Ubuntu *requires* a Linux boot loader. The latter is GRUB 2 by default, but can be any of several other [EFI boot loaders for Linux.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders) The task of a boot *loader* is to load an OS kernel into memory and start it running.

A boot *manager,* OTOH, displays a menu or otherwise provides a way for a user to select what OS to launch. GRUB and the Windows boot loader both provide boot manager functions as well as boot loader functions; but there are programs that provide boot loader functions only or boot manager functions only. In fact, all EFIs provide some sort of boot manager, although in some cases it's so primitive that it's useless.

I've heard that it's possible to configure the Windows boot manager to launch GRUB, even in EFI mode; but I don't know the details of how to do this. You might ask about it on a Windows forum if you want to investigate this approach.

Another alternative, if you don't like the GRUB UI, is to look into another boot manager. For something that's non-intimidating once configured, my own [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) may be to your liking. It presents a graphical view (although it's still keyboard-driven), so it's likely to be less intimidating than the text-mode GRUB. You might want to tweak rEFInd's configuration once it's installed. See its [configuration](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html) and [Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) documentation in particular.

Comment: I will read these articles and follow up.

Comment: efibootmgr helped install grub as the default bootloader. But still I can't add grub to Windows Boot Manager

Comment: I rebooted to windows and guess what, it deleted Grub again. Maybe I need to rename shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi but won't that break its signature?

Comment: I have disabled Secure Boot. I have set rEFInd to boot first still Windows Boot Manager takes control. efibootmgr shows the same boot order as I have set (refind, ubuntu, windows) but still Windows Boot Manager boots first.

Comment: See [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887210/efibootmanager-o-changes-are-lost-on-reboot) for information on dealing with buggy EFIs that lose or forget their boot order settings.

Comment: I fixed the problem by editing boot order from Windows bcdedit. rEFInd looks cool and is very customisable. I think I can continue using it instead of Windows Boot Manager. But still I want to know why can't we add boot entries in Windows Boot Manager.

Comment: From my answer: "I've heard that it's possible to configure the Windows boot manager to launch GRUB, even in EFI mode; but I don't know the details of how to do this."

Comment: I have posted a question in windows forum. Let's see if any one there knows how to do this. Thanks for your continuous support. And your rEFInd is awesome

Comment: @RodSmith Please take a look at this new question: [Installing Ubuntu does not show up after installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053975/installing-ubuntu-does-not-show-up-after-installation/) about a dual boot problem caused by two bootloaders installed alongside each other: grub and Windows Boot Manager.