# Installing Ubuntu does not show up after installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, 18.04

I recently brought my [HP laptop](https://support.hp.com/ie-en/document/c05573385), after installing windows 10 on it I wanted to install Ubuntu on it.

I started off by downloading the disk file (ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64) and putting it on my USB with rufus.

When I booted the usb and got into the installation screen it started to freeze. I solved this by replacing ["quiet splash" to "nomodeset"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349782) in GRUB.

After this the installation process did not freeze again and was finally possible. After restarting the laptop to use the new installation the laptop boots to windows 10 again and when I go to the boot options of the laptop again I contains two OS boot managers, The windows Boot Manager and grub. When booting grub it takes me to the boot console. How do I restart the laptop to the installed Ubuntu and why does it not show up in the boot manager of my BIOS.

Thanks

EDIT: Sort of fixed it by just installing Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80007/discussion-on-question-by-brian-barbieri-installing-ubuntu-does-not-show-up-afte).

Comment: Here is the boot-repair summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gRD68JvqRH/